# How to get a while statement to work with biggest power smaller than x?

Tags: python

```
def gond7(n):
    """
    The parameter n is an int and n > 0.
    The function gond7() should return the biggest eleventh power that is
    smaller than n.

    Example:
    gond7(1000000) should return 177147 as 3 ** 11 == 177147 (and is smaller
    than n) and the next 11th power, 4 ** 11 == 4194304, is not smaller
    than n.
    """

    x = 0
    amount = x ** 11
    while amount <= n:
        x += 1
        amount = x ** 11
    return amount


print gond7(1000000)
```

I can't get this to work in a proper way. So I made this function to get it to work, but because a while statement needs to be gone through before it outputs something, it doesn't show me the correct value.

What am I doing wrong? I am printing:

```
4194304
```

While I want `177147`.

How could I do this? What am I missing?

Comment: `return (x - 1) ** 11` ?

Comment: But isn't there a better way for that @DeepSpace? Wouldn't that suggest that I already know that the while statement will go one further?

Comment: So change the condition so it calculates the next one, like the posted answer suggests.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? How? That's my point. I am stuck, because I can't grasp the idea to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ? not very elegant but it should work

```
def gond7(n):
    x = 0
    amount = x ** 11
    while amount <= n:
        result = amount
        x += 1
        amount = x ** 11
    return result


print gond7(1000000)
```

Comment: This was what I wanted to do, but I couldn't think about HOW exactly. Thanks, Marco!

Answer (score 3):

The last `+= 1` is one too many. You can simplify it to

```
x = 0
while (x + 1) ** 11 < n:
    x += 1
return x ** 11
```

or calculate the value directly by just taking the 11th root of `n`, rounding it down by casting it to an `int` and "powering it back up":

```
return int(n ** (1.0 / 11)) ** 11
#  return int(n ** (1 / 11)) ** 11  suffices in Python3
```

Comment: Thank you! But, is there a different way? I mean, using my example with checking the total amount first in the while statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `amount` *before* you update it. If `amount <= n` but `x ** 11` is greater than `n`, you are returning the larger value.

```
x = 0
amount = 1  # 0 ** 11 == 1
while True:
    new_amount = x ** 11
    if new_amount > n:
        return amount
    amount = new_amount
    x += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the new insights you are all giving me! Appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to see the updated answer; I was computing `11 * x`, not `x ** 11`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def gond7(n):

    x = 0
    amount = x ** 11
    while amount <= n:
        x += 1
        amount = x ** 11
    if amount > n:
        return (x-1)**11
    else:
        return amount


print gond7(1000000)
>177147
```